# docker "Unable to find group docker" using "--group-add docker"

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

I would like to know why `--group-add docker` in the following doesn't work.But I have another priority image that it does work.

```
docker run \
    --rm \
    -it \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    -v /etc/docker/daemon.json:/etc/docker/daemon.json \
    -v /etc/shadow:/etc/shadow \
    -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd \
    -v /etc/sudoers:/etc/sudoers \
    -v /etc/group:/etc/group \
    -u $(id -u):$(id -g) \
    --group-add docker \
    docker/compose:debian-1.27.4 \
    bash
```

it errors out

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Unable to find group docker.
```

I have the same issue with other images like `ubuntu`, `hello-world` and so on. What is needed in the image to be able to add `docker` group?

My system:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- docker 19.03.13

I know I have the `docker` group in the host. I can see it in the output of `groups`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, docker tries to set the groups (as well as uid/gid) **before** it mounts volumes, so the group `docker` (which is defined in `/etc/group` on your host) is not visible at that point inside the container since it is not it the `/etc/group` file contained in the image.

**[Edit]** In modern docker (e.g. 20.10.23) using numerical gid for docker group will do the trick. For example if docker gid is 999 use `--group-add 999` instead of `--group-add docker`.

One possible solution could be to create your own image and put the appropriate `/etc/group` (and possibly `passwd`) file inside it. It's not that convenient as manipulating the compose file only but certainly would do the trick.

Another alternative could be to use [setpriv](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/util-linux/setpriv.1.en.html) as container entry point. Since entry point is executed after the volumes are mounted it can access the content of mounted `/etc/group` file. Other similar tools like [gosu](https://github.com/tianon/gosu) or [su-exec](https://github.com/ncopa/su-exec) do not support auxiliary groups ARAIK, but you may find some security-related information in their documentation that you may need to take into consideration, depending on your use cases.

Answer (score 0):

With you command, you are trying to add current user to the group `docker`, but *inside* docker, not in the host.

As group `docker` does not exist inside docker, reason why you've got error message.

If it's really what you want, you can use `groupadd docker` to create the group, then add the user to the group.

Comment: thanks. If I add the `groupadd` line, it runs the container but the `docker info` command gives me permission error for server inside the container. 

`yousof@5e6d57da4ced:/$ docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
ERROR: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/info: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
errors pretty printing info`

Comment: and also `groups` does not show the `docker` for the current user.